# How to determine the reflex angles in a concave polygon in 3D?

Tags: 3d, angle, polygons, computational-geometry, cross-product

For a concave polygon in 2D, it's easy to use the cross product to determine the reflex angles, which are greater than $180^{\circ}$, but I wonder if there is a simple way to do it in 3D.

Comment: You can always rotate the polygon into the $x$-$y$ plane and do it the same way. Just keep track of which vertices are which.